# how to filter an array of hashmaps

Tags: ruby

I have a hash map of arrays representing colors, shades for each color, and availability of each shade

```
[
 {"color"=>"red", "shades"=>[]}, 
 {"color"=>"yellow", "shades"=>[]}, 
 {"name"=>"Pink", "shades"=>[{"name"=>"lightpink", "available"=>0}]}, 
 {"name"=>"Green", "shades"=>[{"name"=>"darkgreen", "available"=>1}, {"name"=>"lightgreen", "available"=>1},    
    {"name"=>"lightergreen", "available"=>0}]}
}
```

from this array I want to fetch all the shades with `available == 1`

so finally i want this:

```
[ {"name"=>"darkgreen", "available"=>1},
  {"name"=>"lightgreen", "available"=>1}
]
```

How can I get that?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
available_shades = []
all_shades = []
allcolors.each do |color|
  all_shades << color["shades"]
end

available_shades = all_shades.find{|shade| shade["available"] == 1}
```

Comment: What you have is not valid Ruby code.

Comment: You need a final closing `]` on your array of hashes, not a `}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-select)

```
array = [
 {"color"=>"red", "shades"=>[]}, 
 {"color"=>"yellow", "shades"=>[]}, 
 {"name"=>"Pink", "shades"=>[{"name"=>"lightpink", "available"=>0}]}, 
 {"name"=>"Green", "shades"=>[{"name"=>"darkgreen", "available"=>1}, {"name"=>"lightgreen", "available"=>1},    
    {"name"=>"lightergreen", "available"=>0}]}
]

array.flat_map { |x| x["shades"] }.select { |x| x["available"] == 1 }
#=> [
#=>   {"name"=>"darkgreen", "available"=>1},
#=>   {"name"=>"lightgreen", "available"=>1}
#=> ]
```

Comment: It should be `x['shades']`.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as :-

```
array = [
 {"color"=>"red", "shades"=>[]}, 
 {"color"=>"yellow", "shades"=>[]}, 
 {"name"=>"Pink", "shades"=>[{"name"=>"lightpink", "available"=>0}]}, 
 {"name"=>"Green", "shades"=>[{"name"=>"darkgreen", "available"=>1}, {"name"=>"lightgreen", "available"=>1},    
    {"name"=>"lightergreen", "available"=>0}]}
]
ary = array.flat_map do |x| 
  x['shades'].select { |h| h['available'] == 1 } unless x['shades'].empty?
end.compact

ary # => [{"name"=>"darkgreen", "available"=>1}, {"name"=>"lightgreen", "available"=>1}]
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes.. far better.. But if `x['shades']` contains `nil` or `false` then ?